# Probability question - Bayes' Theorem biased coins

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

A bag contains 120 coins: 30 coins come up heads $40\%$ of the time (group a), 30 coins come up heads $20\%$ of the time (group b), and 60 coins have tails on both sides (group c).

I've calculated:

1. I pick a coin at random, toss it, and it comes up tails.  What is the probability that it is from group b?  0.2353
2. I toss that same coin for the second time and it shows tails again. Now hat is the probability that it is from group b? 0.2215

The question I'm stuck on is:
Flipping the same coin for the third time, now it comes up heads. What is the probability that is from group b?  I calculated the answer to be 0.2953

[image: This is my working]

However, my professor has marked this wrong with the following working and answer:

> Flipping the same coin for the third time. Now it comes up heads. What is the probability that is from group b?
>
> P(Head | B) = 0.2
>
> P(Tail) = 0.6 * 0.5  + 0.8 * 0.5 = 0.7
>
> P(B | Tail) = 0.8 * 0.25 / 0.7 = 0.2887
>
> P(Head) = 0.2*0.5 + 0.4 * 0.5 = 0.3
>
> P(B | Tail, Tail) = P(Tail | B) / P(Tail) * P(Tail | B) = 0.8 / 0.7 * 0.2887 = 0.3299
>
> P(B | Head, Tail, Tail) = P(Head | B) / P(Head) * P(B | Tail, Tail) = 0.2 / 0.3 * 0.3299 = 0.2199

I really don't understand how the answer is 0.2199? can someone explain this please? Thank you

Comment: I don't get either answer.  Seeing the $H$ excludes group $C$. Our prior, then, is that it is equally likely to be from either $A$ or $B$.  Thus the answer is $\frac {.8\times .8\times .2}{.8\times .8\times .2+.6\times.6\times .4}\approx .47$ ... I can't really follow the official calculation as it is unclear where equations start and stop.  Just informally, $.6\times .6\times .4=.144$ is only slightly bigger than $.8\times .8\times .2=.128$ so I can't see why one would be so sure this was an $A$ coin.

Comment: Note:  your calculation is wrong because your denominator is wrong.  You can't use a fixed probability for heads and tails the way you do, because the outcomes are not independent. To illustrate this, suppose we had one coin with two heads and another with two tails. Choosing one uniformly at random, the probability that a single toss of your chosen coin is $H$ is $.5$, clearly.  But the probability that two tosses yield $HT$ is $0$, not $.25$

Comment: For q2, I'm getting $\frac{0.25\times0.8^2}{0.25\times0.6^2+0.25\times0.8^2+0.5}=0.213$, which is different to yours

Comment: @jlammy  I agree with your calculation.

Comment: I agree the prof's answer seems off: $80\%$ chance of it being group B seems way too high. @lulu explains it well, chance of TTH is fairly similar for both groups

Comment: @lulu: I edited the post so that the professor's reasoning is more clearly set down (it's often easier in the source for the post), but I'm with you; I haven't spent enough time with this analysis to understand what that professor is on about.

Comment: For what it's worth, in ordinary fractions, I get $4/17$, $16/75$, and $8/17$, in line with OP's, lulu's, and jlammy's answers, respectively.

Comment: @BrianTung  Thanks for doing the editing.  I still can't follow the reasoning though.

Comment: @lulu: It seems to me at first glance that sometimes the professor is eliminating the group C coins, and sometimes they aren't.  It's rather confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$P(B|TTH) = \frac{P(TTH|B)P(B)}{P(TTH)}$$

$$ = \frac{P(TTH|B)P(B)}{P(TTH|A)P(A) + P(TTH|B)P(B) + P(TTH|C)P(C)}$$

Here $P(A)= P(B) = 1/4$, and $P(C) = 1/2$.

- $P(TTH|A) = .8 \cdot .8 \cdot .2$
- $P(TTH|B) = .6 \cdot .6 \cdot .4$
- $P(TTH|C) = 0$

Substituting I get $P(B|TTH) = 0.470588$

And thus, of course $P(A|TTH) = 0.529412$ and $P(C|TTH) = 0$.

---

Your error was your denominator, i.e., your calculation of $P(TTH)$.  Check that (conceptually), realizing the process:  FIRST choose a coin, THEN flip it three times.  You either chose an $A$ or a $B$ or a $C$ coin, and then were "stuck" with it for all the flippings.  See?

The professor is simply confused.  You never have to go through all those intermediate states (e.g., $TT$).